# How to change pitch of music in mplayer?

Tags: mplayer

How to change the pitch of the sound file `mplayer`? I want to make my music sound lower, but not change the speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mplayer -af scaletempo=scale=1.0:speed=pitch -speed 0.8 MUSIC.ogg
```

Set option for `speed` to `pitch` and change the separate option `-speed` to the tone relative to the song. Less than 1 is lower, greater than 1 is higher.

Comment: This changes the speed unfortunately.

Comment: For me, it works.

Comment: Same thing here.... sync is gone. Is there a simpler way to affect pitch straight without modifying sampling rate and video rate?

Comment: Actually, I got it to sync..... keeping scaletempo and -speed parameter on the same value.... but it makes video/audio go slower/faster. Coming back to original request: how about changing pitch (higher/lower) while keeping the original speed on video and audio?